# How can I reverse the page order in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

I need to change the page order of my blog posts so that new posts get ordered to the top instead of the bottom.

Right now, older posts are at the top of the page.

Here's my gatsby-node.js. How can I reverse the order?

```
const path = require('path');

// registering our posts

exports.createPages = ({ boundActionCreators, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = boundActionCreators;

  const postTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/blog-post.js');

  return graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            html
            id
            frontmatter {
              path
              title
              date
              author
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(res => {
    if (res.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(res.errors);
    }
    res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.frontmatter.path,
        component: postTemplate,
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GraphQL result gets passed to your createPage() function where the pages are created in the order given by the result set. You can order the GraphQL result set inside your query:

```
    {
      allMarkdownRemark( sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date]
                                 order: DESC } // order by date descending 
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            html
            id
            frontmatter {
              path
              title
              date
              author
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
```

See the [Gatsby GraphQL documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#sort) for more options.